# Не обновляется информация в админке Joomla после сохранения

Tags: joomla

На сайте установлена Joomla 3.7.5 возникла такая проблема. Когда вношу изменения в какой то пост добавляю текст или наоборот удаляю что-то и нажимаю сохранить изменения применяются но только на самом сайте а в самой админке нечего не меняется как буд-то бы нечего и не делал, в чем проблема может быть, может кто-то подскажет?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена с добавлением 3х строчек в файл php.ini

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```